# how to make the tab key skip the data grid in WPF, instead of moving from a field to another while pressing the tab key

Tags: c#, wpf

how to make the tab key skip the data grid in WPF, C#. So instead of moving from a field to another while pressing the tab key, i need the tab key skip the data grid once it is there without moving from a field to another?

Comment: Have you tried IsTabStop property?

Answer (score 0):

You need to suppress the event of the tab key and add your own logic instead.

First add an event handler (In code or XAML):

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MainWindow_KeyDown);
}
```

Then, Implement your logic:

```
void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

        FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(parentElement, theElementAfterTheGridID);
    }
}
```

I haven't test it but it should be close to that code.

Of course, this will happen on **every** tab press, It depends how you want it to behave. You can also check if the focused element is the grid or a cell of that grid.